# Autocomplete with Ajax XML

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, autocomplete

I want to make a autocomplete to my input field.
All the data is fetched from my database and handled with my autocomplete.php file - its works fine and is storing all the matching columns in a XML file which is sent back to the server.
Onkeyup i GET send with q= "the typed string" to the autocomplete.

Im having trouble handling the XML file when its received from the server. My plan is to append all the matching results to my datalist, which will work as a autocomplete?
Here is my code:

```
<input id="showCustomerId" name="customer" type="text" min="1" max="100" list="customerlist" required>
<datalist id="customerlist"></datalist>
```

script:

```
$("#showCustomerId").on('keyup', function(){
                var str = document.getElementById('showCustomerId').value;
                var xmlhttp;
                if (str.length===0) {
                    document.getElementById("customerlist").innerHTML="";
                    return;
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else{// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                        var docroot= xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
                        var customers = docroot.getElementsByTagName('customer');
                        for(var i=0; i<customers.length; i=i++){
                            var option = customers[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
                            $("#customerlist").append("<option value=\"" +option+ "\">");
                        }
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","ini/search-customers.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            });
```

autocomplete.php

```
$q=$_GET['q'];
$result = // do query;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $xml->addChild("customer",$row['customer_id']);
}
header('Content-type:text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

Right now my problem is not getting the value, when i alert the result in xml handler function i get the right values, but when i do the code like i have here, my website freezes!
I got the values, but i just cant append them to my datalist the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess Easiest way to build autocomplete is by jQuery Autocomplete or Twitter Typehead. So simple jquery is better suited for this situation. Add jQuery Latest version in head
Code is not tested.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Assuming #customerlist is the ID of the text box which you need to see autocomplete
//No need to get value also - by default
$("#customerlist").autoComplete({source:"ini/search-customers.php"});

// Same time autocomplete send term as default GET variable

});
```

At serverside - search-customers.php

```
$q=$_GET['term'];
$result = // do query;
$json = new Array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json[] = $row['customer_id'];
}
header('Content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: it would be easier, but there is a good reason it needs to be with xml.